# Pear/Quickform2: Is there something like the method "setRequiredNote" in Quickform2?

Tags: php, forms, pear, quickform

I used the method `setRequiredNote` of HTML_QuickForm but I can't find a similar method in QuickForm2.
Has anybody an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the renderer now, option "required_note":

```
$renderer->setOption('required_note', '* This fields are required');
```

See http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform2.renderers.php

Comment: On the first view this seemed to be helpful. On the second view I unfortunatly got the error message: HTML_QuickForm2_NotFoundException: Unknown option 'required_node' in pear\HTML\QuickForm2\Renderer\Proxy.php    I only had a previouse call to $renderer = HTML_QuickForm2_Renderer::factory('default'); From this point of view I don't know why I got this error from Proxy.php?   Peter

Comment: I had a mistake in it, it's no*t*e, not no*d*e.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have found out this by myself :-)